# My desktop/laptop can't ping each other over wired Ethernet, only over Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ping

I have this weird thing going on whenever I connect my desktop or laptop via an Ethernet cable, it seems that it becomes isolated. It can't ping anything and nothing can ping it.

I already checked and everything is in the same subnet, and as soon as I change to Wi-Fi I'm able to ping again.

Notice this is not only about not being able to ping other devices: If the device is connected via Ethernet cable it can't be pinged by other devices.

192.168.2.111 is connected via Ethernet and can't be pinged.

192.168.2.111 is connected via Wi-Fi and can only be pinged when I change to Wi-Fi on my desktop.

PS: I already tried disabling the firewall.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried releasing and renewing the DHCP lease?

Comment: Normally IP addresses are bound to MAC addresses which means that each interface will have its own address.  So if you change the interface the device connects witj you likely need to ping its new IP.

Comment: Are you connecting an Ethernet cable directly between the laptop and the desktop, or are you connecting them both into your home Ethernet network? What IP subnet are you using for the Ethernet LAN? What IP subnet are you using for the Wi-Fi network? Something about the way you phrased your question makes it sound  like you might be using an isolated Ethernet LAN (such as a direct cable between hosts), but trying to use the same IP subnet as you used on Wi-Fi, which won't work. Separate LANs need separate IP subnets.

Comment: @Spiff
Both the laptop and the desktop are connected to my home network.

After running ipconfig /release:

Desktop: 192.168.2.100
laptop: 192.168.2.105

Pinging 192.168.2.105 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.2.100: Destination host unreachable.

Comment: @John I don't think it does, not sure how to check. But would it prevent devices from seen each other over ethernet?